# How much RAM for a web server?

Tags: iis, hardware, asp.net, memory

I am designing hardware requirements for ASP.NET web application. When it comes to memory, how much RAM does a web server need to work efficiently (use full processing power of CPUs)? Are there any approximations of GB RAM per core or something like that?

The application is a classic intranet one, with lots of heavy ASP.NET stuff (ViewState) and very few static content, so it is more CPU-bound.

Comment: The good people at ServerFault might be more qualified to help you; also, the requirements depend greatly on the applications that will run on your server (not all web applications are similar in resource requirements). Can you be a bit more specific about the apps you're planning to host there?

Comment: -1: Needs real performance data to answer this with anything more than "it depends".

Comment: No chance to answer this correctly without more details. How many concurrent request, sql data binding, etc...

Comment: 512GB for a webserver is fine.  If there are no users!

Please provide us with more details:  How many concurrenty users do you want to support?  How does the server perform in your dev and test environments?

Comment: 16TB will probably be enough, at least for starters. If you care to supply useful information we can probably give you a better estimate.

Comment: Question: How much RAM for a web server? Answer: Enough.

Answer (score 2):

depends what kind of website and how much users/ hits/minute. Does it run a DB as well? 
i think with 4GB (which isnt expensive these days) you'll be able to have some serious traffic :)

Comment: It is quite possible that a server doing mostly calculations could saturate lots of cores and the network before using much memory. A different style of usage would have different requirements. So the only answer with the given information is *"it depends"*.